# Flot jQuery last 30 ticks

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Im looking how to set in flot to display the last 30 ticks(to pan the y axis to show last 30), the x axis is in the time mode, i review few doc's about flot, but i didn't found something helpful , maybe i missed that so im writing here.

Comment: Show what code you have thus far?

Comment: I pasted my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043717/javascript-flot-chart-using-timestamps  but there no one responded to my questions about ticks scale, i simply wan't to display current last 30 days